# VB functions and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to access VB functions using C#? I am trying to create an interface for a sensor, whose files are given in VB format. How can i access  themm and consequently make changes in the same?

Ok! sorry for incomplete info. The files i have are .vbp and .frm format. I am trying to create a Form file(interface, with buttons etc.) using Microsoft Visual Studio2008, which has a included wrapper to combine C++ and C# and has console application. Now how do i call the .vbp files and to furthur work on the interface?

Comment: With "file" you mean "code file"? And is it VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: Your going to have to provide more details, this doesn't make any sense as written.

Comment: If you are talking about VB .Net, then you could use inheritance to create your own classes.

Comment: Ok! sorry for incomplete info. The files i have are .vbp and .frm format. I am trying to create a Form file(interface, with buttons etc.) using Microsoft Visual Studio2008, which has a included wrapper to combine C++ and C# and has console application. Now how do i call the .vbp files and to furthur work on the interface?

Answer (score 3):

If you have VB.NET code files, compile them into a class library (i.e. a DLL), then reference that library from your C# project.